# Will the return of Christ (Second Coming) be literal or symbolic?

Tags: jesus

I know the Book of Revelation is highly symbolic but does that mean Christ's coming is also symbolic as well? To me it seems as if he returns for the individual in judgment and the whole in redemption.

Comment: @All I believe there are the makings of a good question here, however as it stands there needs some adjustment to determine the OP's intent.

Comment: @user2479 The OP's intent seems pretty clear. It might be a good question, but it's off topic for this site. It's not about a textual issue, it's looking for a doctrinal position. This site isn't about presenting doctrinal positions (even with textual support). We only handle things the other way around.

Comment: @Caleb It is precisely for this reason that I felt an edit was needed. IF: One was ascertaining whether or not Jesus's 2nd Coming was Literal, one could clearly establish it from the text and consequently(IMO) it would be a very valid question. On the other hand, if all one is trying to do is establish that everything in Revelations is Figurative, and therefore one can establish another conclusion than what is plainly written in the text, then unless one is asking a hermeneutics question(they might....?) THEN:I would concede it is off-topic.

Comment: @Gabe I know you're new here, and perhaps aren't aware of the rules for posting questions on this site. An edit has been suggested, but I sense it's not in line with what your asking. Based on my comment to Caleb, could you clarify your intention? Then perhaps we can pose a question that will pass the board of censors. Thx